# How to set up default 'elastic' user password while running official Elasticsearch docker image?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose, elasticsearch-x-pack

I want to use official [Elasticsearch docker image](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/docker.html) via **docker-compose.yml** as official documentation suggests:

My simplified **docker-compose.yml** looks like the following:

```
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.2
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
```

By default after running `docker-compose up` I have user `elastic`being created with default password `changeme`. As [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/security-getting-started.html) suggests I may change user password by calling:

```
curl -XPUT -u elastic 'localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/elastic/_password' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "password" : "elasticpassword"
}'
```

But this would require additional step while running Docker image.

**Is there a way to configure default `elastic` user password during `docker-compose up` command? Maybe through environment variables somehow or via `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file?**

I could create my own image as a wrapper on top of `docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.2` image and `RUN` `curl ...` command as a part of related Dockerfile but it seems like overhead to me to create my own version of Elasticsearch image just to configure `elastic` user password...

Comment: If you just use 

    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.2

the Username/Password Security won't work. You will need an docker image with X-pack/Shield installed as a plugin which can be done using a dockerfile. 

However please note that unless you add the license key in X-Pack plugin it won't start.

If you are using any web server like nginx or Traefik, they can be extended to use  Basic Authentication. Could that be a better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to put **nginx** proxy container with basic authentication in front of **elasticsearch** container. Nginx config may look something like:

```
upstream elasticsearch {
    server elasticsearch:9200;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server.name.com;

    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Where .htpasswd contains user name and encrypted user password (you may use even online services to generate it like http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/).

Other than that you may just buy a licence for [X-pack/Shield](https://www.elastic.co/products/x-pack/security) and use it instead if you wish.